# how two make xcode generate a warning when no default with enum switch

Tags: c, xcode, clang, llvm

blow code this is no warning in xCode. how to make xCode generate a warning.

```
enum Color{
    RED=3,
    BLACK
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    enum Color currentColor = BLACK;
    switch (currentColor) {
        case RED:
            break;
        case BLACK:
            break;
        //default:
        //  break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why should there be a warning? It's valid C. `default` is optional.

Comment: what warning is expected?

Comment: Try adding a third value to the enum, so the default isn't provably dead code.

Comment: Compilers are quite smart these days. If you cover all values of an enum, there is no need for a default, and if you don't, they warn (given respective option). -- If you want dogmatic compliance to your coding style, use some separated static analyzer.

Comment: i need not default warning for some reason

Comment: Most people prefer a warning if there is an enum value that isn't handled by the switch(), but if an explicit default case is what you want it should be simple to implement. You need to write an LLVM pass that looks at all switch instructions and warns if any [switch's default case](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1SwitchInst.html#a7aaa70580c7a6efa1739d9fbd19063dd) has no line number (ie. is a compiler-generated noop). I'm afraid I don't know how to plug user-supplied passes into xcode.